# ¿Como elimino elementos de una ventana abierta con "window.open"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una ventana que abro con siguiente código:

```
let locacizacion = window.location.origin+'/persona';
window.open(locacizacion, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
```

Pero quisiera que no aparezca con los elementos resaltados en la imagen de abajo.
[image: imagen]

¿Esto se puede? He estado buscando y no consigo algo parecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open` no puede eliminar una parte de la pagina ya que no provee una API para eso.

Por eso, tendras que enviar un parametro que le indice a la pagina `/persona` que elimine la cabezera. Y en la pagina `/persona` lees si existe ese parametro y ocultas/eliminas la cabezera.

Por ejemplo supongamos que la cabezera esta dentro de un `div` con el id `cabezera`. Le especificas el parametro que indicara si ocultas o no:

```
let locacizacion = window.location.origin+'/persona?ocultar_cabezera=true';
window.open(locacizacion, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
```

Y en tu pagina lees si existe un parametro `ocultar_cabezera=true` y lo ocultas:

```
if(location.search.indexOf('ocultar_cabezera=true') > 1)
{
  document.getElementById("cabezera").style.display = "none";
}
```